# where can I make free space for Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uefi, gpt

For this disk:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.14393.0

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: BUDDY

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     C   Acer         NTFS   Partition    915 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 1         Recovery     NTFS   Partition    600 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 2         ESP          FAT32  Partition    300 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 3         Push Button  NTFS   Partition     15 GB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     D   Transcend    FAT32  Removable    117 GB  Healthy
```

The `diskmgmt.msc` utility shows:

[image]

Can I shrink the `C` drive to make free space for Linux?

Comment: Short answer: yes, you can.

Comment: I believe your right. And your link is broken too!

Comment: bonus points for explaining why there are multiple recovery partitions.

Comment: @Thufir - You'll have to ask Acer about that one...

Comment: Or Microsoft. I don't know whether those recovery partitions are a Windows or a computer manufacturer thing, but they are definitely not related to Ubuntu and therefore that "bonus question" would be off-topic. Might be valid on [su] instead though.

Comment: on IRC, they said that the first one was Windows PE, pre-install Environment.  That trivia question answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see the link, but seeing the EFI partition I assume that it is a GUID partition table (GPT). So yes, you can use Windows to shrink C: (and leave unallocated drive space).

Reboot from a live Ubuntu drive and use the unallocated space. Either let the Ubuntu installer do it, or prepare it with gparted and select 'Something else' in the partitioning window of the installer.